# Fill tables from multiple JSON files with different columns

Tags: php, database, laravel, api, external

I have an Laravel app that receives a post request (json), from an external source. 
This source is the main source of my data.

I receive 4 objects with over 18000 records. So 4 x 18k

I have a laravel script that goes through all the files.

Per file it checks the content, picks each row and flattens the array.

Then it checks if the column (key) exists.

.. This happens 4 x 18.000 times. 
And then it fills each table with corresponding values.

Is there a way that looks through 1 file and gives all the keys without going through all the records 1 by 1?

E. G. For the file bikes i have:

Bike1 has [1 = 'a', 2 ='b', 4 = '1w3'] Bike2 has [1 = 'Abc', 3 = '123', 4 = '2444']

And i want to get 
BikeKeys = [1, 2, 3, 4]

From there i create migration,

After this i check each value from record in DB and store in model.

But how do i get the different columns from all the records if they can differ from keys? 
(Without going through all?)

I want to create foreign keys and pivots after importing. Because every table contains duplicate columns.

TLDR: How do i create a import model from external data source? And how can i merge all duplicate columns, new tables and foreign keys? That the source providez

(Without creating index() not Found?)

Answer (score 0):

Now i Itirate through each file, 
Checks all the records, 
Returns key per record.

Create column of key if not exists. 
Fills key

Checks for next file & do store
Value